# How to get data from Firebase and show them in grid view?

Tags: flutter

I have some [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xakIO.png) in firebase real time database. I want to show them in gridview and if I click on any item it will take me another page. How can I do it?

I am doing this code for printing values of my data:

```
void printFirebase(){
    dbRef.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      print('pets : ${snapshot.value}');
    });
  }
```

```
Column(
              children: <Widget> [
                ElevatedButton(onPressed: printFirebase,
                    child: Text('click'),
                )
              ],
          ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a StreamBuilder and return a GridView with Children through a stream

```
     StreamBuilder(
                    stream: firebaseFirestore
                        .collection(widget.sportName)
                        .snapshots(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                        );
                      }
                      return GridView.count(
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        crossAxisCount: 5,
                        mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                        childAspectRatio: 1,
                        crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                        children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                          return GestureDetector(
                            child:
                                dateSelector(document['date'], document.id),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      );
                    },
                  ),
```

Comment: actually, I am using Firebase( Real Time Database). So, how should I write code for getting my data from real time database and show them in Grid view?
I have data of 'pets'. There are pets having different 'name', 'age' and 'type'. I want to show each pets data in a clickable card/box and cards/boxes will be in Grid.